# Mysql trigger to copy id from one column to another in same table when record is created

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, mysql-5.5

I need to copy id field from one column to another when new record is created. Number must be same in both column and in best case it should be inserted in same moment in to the database. Best solution which i found is probably to use triggers.

I created sql like this:

```
TRIGGER `db`.`copy_id_into_mbc_id` BEFORE INSERT ON `my_table` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET NEW.mbc_id = (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA='mbc' and TABLE_NAME='my_table');
END
```

This solution seems working but i need to know if it is safe. I read some old topic as some peoples says it can cause race condition. I'm not sure in which case this is risky as from my test it seems fine.

Is there any better way to be sure that both column have exactly same value when it is inserted? Id field is auto incremented and in code i don't know it until record is created but update second field in this moment is to late for me.

So my question are: With this trigger value in both column will be always same when new record is created? Is there better way to keep both value same in mysql 5.5 or in doctrine/php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, val INT);
> ```

> ```sql
> CREATE TRIGGER tr
> BEFORE INSERT 
> ON test 
> FOR EACH ROW
> SET NEW.val = ( SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT 
>                 FROM information_schema.TABLES 
>                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE()
>                   AND TABLE_NAME='test' );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO test (id)
> SELECT NULL UNION ALL SELECT NULL;
>
> SELECT * FROM test;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | val
> -: | --:
>  1 |   1
>  2 |   1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d13b0b616debcc63f37e370e16f21f43)*

---

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, val INT);
> ```

> ```sql
> CREATE TRIGGER tr
> BEFORE INSERT 
> ON test 
> FOR EACH ROW
> SET NEW.val = ( SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT 
>                 FROM information_schema.TABLES 
>                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE()
>                   AND TABLE_NAME='test' );
> ```

> ```sql
> CREATE PROCEDURE fill ()
> BEGIN
>     DECLARE cnt INT DEFAULT 0;
>     WHILE cnt < 2 DO
>         INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (NULL);
>         SET cnt := cnt + 1;
>     END WHILE;
> END;;
> ```

> ```
> CALL fill();
> SELECT * FROM test;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | val
> -: | --:
>  1 |   1
>  2 |   1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3eb137f2c621823ee2f443d9aa2ea711)*

Comment: this example from js fiddle works fine if i change mysql version to 5.5. there is some difference on mysql 8.0 which cause this trigger to work worst than in previous version

Comment: @patryno If you are sure that (1) you will never upgrade your MySQL version; (2) this will always work correctly on your version (like `SELECT * FROM test WHERE val LIKE 'x%'` returns rows ordered according to primary index until the index by `val, foo` created) then no problems, use this technique. Possible problems in the future - at your expense.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, if i don't get more in next few days i will accept your :)

Comment: The proposed solution here does not work anymore for MySQL v8 because it updates the INFORMATION schema only once per 24h. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/65996700/2988107