# PROBLEM WITH - AUTO_INCREMENT VALUE IN TABLE_SCHEMA NOT UPDATING

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

SCENARIO

1. ALTER TABLE {TABLE NAME} AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
2. INSERT INTO {TABLE NAME} ({COLUMN}) VALUES (1);
   (this is only record in table after auto increment was updated)
3. SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES
   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = {DATABASE NAME}
   AND TABLE_NAME = {TABLE NAME};

the last select auto_increment is returning the old value before execution alter table in step 1) and I don't understand why and hot to fix it or maybe alter table in step 1) is not correct way to reset auto_increment.

THX

PS. I know a bit but not everything. I was researching this problem and didn't find satisfactory/explanatory answer.

Comment: make a primary key to the column that you want to set auto increment

Comment: Just a question. Why do you need this information from the information schema? You can get the last I’d by selecting max() and you normally can fetch the last I’d always by using lastInsertID after insert

Comment: I like to understated why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The INFORMATION_SCHEMA doesn't update to reflect recent alterations. MySQL 8.0 changed it so it only updates once every 24 hours.

You can set this:

```
SET GLOBAL information_schema_stats_expiry=0;
```

That will make INFORMATION_SCHEMA update immediately, at the cost of some overhead on your system.

Answer (score 4):

I had the issue where the information schema wasn't being immediately updated.

To fix this I ran:

```
SET PERSIST information_schema_stats_expiry = 0;
```

As using SET GLOBAL didn't work for me.

Hope this helps somebody else.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to take the performance hit of setting `information_schema_stats_expiry` to zero, you can run `ANALYZE TABLE {TABLE NAME}` to update the record for just the table you're interested in.  (See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53855219/10898875) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53855652/10898875).)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you must set AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 not 0